# How to show that mean and median are the same if the distribution is symmetrical

Tags: self-study, descriptive-statistics

Given a set of observations denoted by $x_1,...,x_n$, how to show that the mean $\bar{x}$ and the median $\tilde{x}$ are the same if the distribution is symmetrical? My book says so, but I'm having trouble seeing that from the definitions of $\bar{x}$ and $\tilde{x}$. The book doesn't provide a definition for a symmetrical distribution, but I intuit we can define it to mean that $f(\tilde{x}+c)=f(\tilde{x}-c)$ for any number $c$, where $f(x)$ is the absolute frequency of $x$. Is this definition correct? If so, how to proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: The median of $n$ observations is not well-defined when $n$ is even;, say $n=2k$; it can be taken to be any number between $x_(k)$ and $x_{(k+1)}$, not necessarily the average of these two numbers. For $n=2k+1$, $x_{(k+1)}$ is the unique median for distinct observations.  In any case, the _mean_ of $n$ observations, _even if the observations are drawn as independent samples from a symmetric distribution_ is rarely equal to the mean of the distribution or $c$, the point of symmetry of the distribution. Distinguish between _sample parameters_ and _population parameters_.

Comment: Order the observations and define the median conventionally so it is the middle value in order if $n$ is odd and the mean of the two middle values (the "comedians", according to S.M. Stigler and R. Koenker) otherwise. Then symmetry implies that each difference between the median and any value above is cancelled by a corresponding difference of opposite sign between the median and the symmetrically placed value below it. So, the sum of deviations, $x -$ median, is 0. But this is a characterisation of the mean, and hence the mean and the median are identical in this case.

Comment: For any distribution with 3 or more elements, you can remove $x_1$ and $x_n$, and the median is unchanged.  In a symmetric distribution, observations come in symmetrical pairs around the mean, so removing these two elements will not affect the mean either.  Rinse, repeat until you have one/two centre elements left.

Comment: As pointed out by @DilipSarwate, you are confused between sample mean/median, and distribution expectation/median. The result only holds for the later.

Comment: This question, applied to distributions rather than samples, is asked and answered in many threads here: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mean+median+symmetrical.